# App store distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

Earlier tonight I submitted my app to the store, by selecting iOS device from schemes in Xcode and then performing an Archive (after ensuring bundle/plist info was correct).

I have a distribution profile and cert on my Mac, however before I did a clean archive I didn't change my code signing at a project or target level to distribution, they were still set to code sign with my development profiles/cert.

I opened organiser (without realising the above) and it validated my app for submission and accepted it.

My app is now in waiting for review, my question is:

A) Is this OK? - I think I remember last time (a couple of years ago) I had to instruct Xcode to sign with my distribution cert/provisioning profile.

B) Does Xcode automatically use these profiles/certs behind the scenes now a days, if your archiving with iOS device as the build platform?

I'm wondering why they allowed me submit something that's seemingly signed incorrectly according to the Apple docs.

Thanks,
John

Comment: `I'm wondering why they allowed me submit something that's seemingly signed incorrectly according to the Apple docs.` -- Apparently they don't check that during submission.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually you can't submit app that signed by developer certificate.  
App could be submitted to iTunesConnect only in case if it's signed by distribution certificate that is generated specially for Appstore.  
According to John's question: it seems that he built app with developer certificate but then app was resigned due one of the steps of uploading app to the iTunesConnect, but John didn't make attention on this step. If question will reopened I could provide more explanation with screenshots of this trick.

Comment: @Visput, Hi the question is still open! :) I am wondering if It's OK or I should reject binary and re submit?

Comment: @JohnWoods everything OK, please see my answer.

Comment: I would guess that Xcode assumed your default distribution profile from the app bundle ID. The process would not finish correctly if it was not using a valid distribution profile. This is just my intuition of course... If you are really worried about it, I guess you can cancel and re-submit without any consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't submit app that signed by developer certificate.
App could be submitted to iTunesConnect only in case if it's signed by distribution certificate that is generated specially for Appstore.
it seems that you build app with developer certificate but then app was resigned due one of the steps of uploading app to the iTunesConnect:
[image: Code sign]

It is the first step after entering credentials to iTunesConnect.
If there was selected distribution certificate then it's possible that you didn't make attention on it.

Answering on your questions:
A) It's not OK, but application signed by developer certificate couldn't be uploaded to iTunesConnect.

B) Xcode doesn't select correct certificate automatically behind the scenes but it provides "advices" for developers.